# How to get the value to the drop box by clicking the update button angular

Tags: angular, dropdown, edit, clicking

I tried to send the data to my Dropbox in my angular project but I couldn't get any selected data to that Dropbox. I want it when the update button clicked in my main table. and I used patchvalue to get the data to other text fields but dropdown value to coming.

[select tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYTDl.png)

[edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYHzG.png)

[get and put the data to fields function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOSe1.png)

Comment: in Angular it's used "binding" and "two-way-binding" (related variables in .ts with the .html). Use [(ngModel)](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control). NOTE: **please** don't post images (they are hard to read and no accesible). Instead of include them, write the code, select it and use CTRL+K to formatted as code in your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the note, however I couldn't get the data to my drop down after edit button press.

Comment: I added an answer, I hope this makes my comment more clear.

Answer (score 0):

complementary my comment
In .ts

```
variable=''
```

In .html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="variable">
  <option value='' disable hidden>Select customer</option>
  <option *ngFor="let customerValue of customers" [value]="customerValue.id">
      {{customerValue.userName}}</option>
</select>
<button (click)="getCustomer()">get data</button>
```

You function getCustomer

```
getCustomer()
{ 
   //in this.variable you get the "id" of the selected customer
   console.log(this.variable)
   //If you need  the customer you need find in the list of the customers
   console.log(this.customers.find(x=>x.id==this.variable))
}
```

NOTE: You need import the FormsModule in your module
NOTE2: you can "split" the [(ngModel)] in the way

```
<select [ngModel]="variable" 
     (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;doSomething($event)">
       ...
</select>

doSomething(value:any)
{
    //here value is the "id" of the selected customer
}
```

NOTE4: Really seeing your GetOrderById, I think that you should use ReactiveFormsControls. But in the form you should use the "id" of the customer, not the customerName. Some similar to

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
    <select formControlName="customerId"...>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: value is coming to the console but it's not coming to the Dropbox, if i change the drop box to text field its Woking fine, but I need that value to the dropdown.

Comment: @ChathurangaBandara, check if you have a typo error in the name of the variables, should be the same using a select or an input